# how to write Unit test for Singleton class in Java?

Tags: java, spring, singleton, junit5

I am stuck while writing unit test for singleton class. I tried below things -
when Singletone.getInstance(1) run it is returning Null point exception. Can you please let me know what should be the solution for this?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)    
@PrepareForTest({Singletone.class})
public class SingletoneTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Singletone.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        AddUserDAO addUser = mock(AddUserDAO.Class);
        when(Singletone.getInstance(1).getDAO()).thenReturn(addUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*`when(Singletone.getInstance(1).getDAO())`*" - We have to mock both call separately, so we have to configure the first mock `when(Singleton.getInstance(1)).thenReturn(someMock);` and then configure the second nock `when(someMock.getDAO()).thenReturn(addUser);`

Comment: Why does `getInstance` take parameters if you have actual singletons? Plus, if you're using Spring, you should almost certainly not be using a _structural_ singleton, just a _managed_ singleton where it's an ordinary object but Spring takes care of reusing it.

Comment: what's the purpose of your unit test? are you trying to test just class here? unit testing is not about whether your class is singleton or not.

Comment: I tried with this way -  
   when(Singleton.getInstance(1)).thenReturn(someMock); and then configure the second nock when(someMock.getDAO()).thenReturn(addUser);                                                                               but in first check it return null pointer exception.                                                                Also to answer the question what is the purpose of it. One of the old method used to get this class to dao object to make the database calls.